# Why does my code keep looping the motor function code?

Tags: c++, arduino, platformio

Essentially as the title says the motor moving function keeps looping. And it stops printing the IR values to the serial, essentially it just keeps running the motor function.

I know this is probably stupid simple, and i should know it but the thing is that this is hacked together with code snippets online and i dont have any experience with c++ so.............. |{o_o}|

```
//why? i have no idea but platformio put it here so must be important
#include <arduino.h>
//include the ir remote stuff
#include <IRremote.h> 

//Controls speed of motors
int MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE = 150;

// the pin where you connect the output pin of IR sensor
int RECV_PIN = D5;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
unsigned long key_value = 0; // variable to store the key value

void setup() 
{
    //Right Motor
    pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);

    //Left Motor
    pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    irrecv.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() 
{
    if (irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
        if (results.value == 0xFFFFFFFF) // if the value is equal to 0xFFFFFFFF
        {
            results.value = key_value; // set the value to the key value
        }

        Serial.println(" ");     
        Serial.print("Code: ");     
        Serial.println(results.value); //prints the value a a button press

    }

    key_value = results.value; // store the value as key_value
    irrecv.resume(); // reset the receiver for the next code
    
    //WHY DOES IT KEEP LOOPING & WHY ARE NO OTHER COMMANDS COMING IN??????
    if (results.value == 0xFF30CF)
    {
        Forward();
    }
    irrecv.resume();

}

void Reverse()
{
    digitalWrite(D2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D3, LOW);
    analogWrite(D1, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    analogWrite(D4, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    delay(500);
    motorOff();
}

void Forward()
{
    digitalWrite(D1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
    analogWrite(D2, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    analogWrite(D3, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    delay(5000);
    motorOff();
}
    
void TurnLeft()
{
    digitalWrite(D1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D3, LOW);
    
    analogWrite(D2, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    analogWrite(D4, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    motorOff();
}

void TurnRight()
{
    digitalWrite(D2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
    analogWrite(D1, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    analogWrite(D3, MAX_PWM_VOLTAGE);
    motorOff();
}

void motorOff()
{
    digitalWrite(D1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(D3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(D4,LOW);
}
```

Comment: the loop function will keep looping forever, it's how it's meant to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a volatile qualifier in the declaration of the results:

```
volatile decode_results results;
```

Here is some info on why is it necessary to use volatile:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/variable-scope-qualifiers/volatile/